# Get the right size of android status bar and apply it to HTML?

Tags: android, cordova, statusbar, transparent

I am making a web app and I am using cordova/phonegap. I have different themes in this app and I want to make the status bar color change with the theme so I decided to make the app full screen with a fixed transparent (translucent) status bar so the color would change behind it. In the HTML, I added a small top padding of 20px for the statusbar. The problem is that the status bar is not the same size on all android devices but I set the status bar height to 20px but on some devices it's not 20px! Can I get device's status bar height and apply it to the status bar height in the HTML? Thanks for your help and answer!

Comment: Can you add code to your post ?

Comment: Just forgot to mention, I am using Framework7 so I have the code from there https://framework7.io/docs/status-bar.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is the following:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
    var initialHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeFunction);
    function resizeFunction() {
        console.log('STATUS BAR HEIGHT', document.documentElement.clientHeight - initialHeight);
        window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeFunction);
    }
    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
});
```

It takes about 150ms from `deviceready`, which you can "hide" by showing the SplashScreen a bit longer :)

Answer (score -1):

A better solution might be to leave the statubar as default (have it overload your webview)

In `config.xml`

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
```

and change its color based on the theme your loading

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    if ( /* theme  */ )
        StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#C0C0C0");
}
```